# Read more functionality is not working using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, undefined

I am pretty new to javascript. I am trying to create a *read more/read less* functionality using vanilla javascript but I am facing issues. Whenever I try to fetch and change the `data-address` attribute it is giving me an undefined error. I don't know where I am getting it wrong.

Thank you for the help.

Here is the code:

index.html

```
<div class="col s12" id="address-col">
    <p  class="address"  style="height:50px;overflow:hidden;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, illum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas esse suscipit temporibus consectetur iure quasi magni tenetur quia reprehenderit nesciunt, a nobis, quidem autem consequatur, hic aperiam modi excepturi delectus quo odio quaerat. Sunt id illo praesentium dolorum, inventore iusto?
    </p>
    <span class="read-more" data-address="0">Read more</span>
</div>
```

app.js

```
    var read_more = document.querySelector(".read-more");// read more button
    console.log(read_more);
    var address_div = document.querySelector("#address-col");// content DIV
    console.log(address_div);
    var address_content = document.querySelector(".address"); // content under the DIV
    var intro_height = address_content.offsetHeight; // height of the content
    var address_flag = read_more.getAttribute("data-address"); // fetching attribute of the button
    console.log(address_flag);

    read_more.addEventListener("click",introexpand);
    function introexpand(){
        if(address_flag == 0){
            address_div.style.maxHeight= "none";
            address_div.style.overflow = 'none';
            address_flag=read_more.setAttribute("data-address", "1");
            console.log(address_flag);
        }
        else if(address_flag == 1){
            address_div.style.maxHeight= '12px'; 
            address_div.style.overflow = 'none';
            address_flag=read_more.setAttribute("data-address", "0");
            console.log(address_flag);

        }

    }
```

Comment: You're setting `address_flag` to the return value of `setAttribute()`, which is always [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute). Do `read_more.setAttribute("data-address", "0");` and `address_flag = 0;` separately.

Comment: Yup I did resolved it but still the functionality is working and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are expecting output something like below:

```js
var read_more = document.querySelector(".read-more"); // read more button
console.log(read_more);
var address_div = document.querySelector("#address-col"); // content DIV
console.log(address_div);
var address_content = document.querySelector(".address"); // content under the DIV
var intro_height = address_content.offsetHeight; // height of the content
var address_flag = read_more.getAttribute("data-address"); // fetching attribute of the button
console.log(address_flag);
address_content.style.maxHeight = "18px";

read_more.addEventListener("click", introexpand);

function introexpand() {
  if (address_flag == 0) {
    address_content.style.maxHeight = "50px";
    address_flag = read_more.setAttribute("data-address", "1");
    address_flag = read_more.getAttribute("data-address");
    read_more.innerText = "Read less";
    // console.log(address_flag);
  } else if (address_flag == 1) {
    address_content.style.maxHeight = '18px';
    address_flag = read_more.setAttribute("data-address", "0");
    address_flag = read_more.getAttribute("data-address");
    read_more.innerText = "Read more";
    // console.log(address_flag);

  }

}
```

```html
<div class="col s12" id="address-col">
    <p  class="address"  style="max-height:50px;overflow:hidden;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, illum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas esse suscipit temporibus consectetur iure quasi magni tenetur quia reprehenderit nesciunt, a nobis, quidem autem consequatur, hic aperiam modi excepturi delectus quo odio quaerat. Skunt id illo praesentium dolorum, inventore iusto?
    </p>
    <span class="read-more" data-address="0">Read more</span>
```

But, My suggestion is to play with this example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_read_more.asp which is way better for "Read More Read Less Feature" and most people using on their website with their own customisations. Hope it helps, Thanks :)

Comment: It works like a charm I did some more tweaks. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`setAttribute()` method returns nothing (what is equality to `undefined` value).

If you want log new value of `data-address` attribute, you should read that one more time: so:

```js
            address_flag=read_more.setAttribute("data-address", "1");
            address_flag = read_more.getAttribute("data-address");
            console.log(address_flag);
```

Beside of that, you should rewrite your `introexpand()` function. You should get value `address_flag` attribute at the beginning of function (because `address_flag` is variable with simple type data [string in this case], and you should know that simple type data in JavaScript do not have reference characteristic, and you do not get the most resent value for this specific attribute):

```js
    function introexpand(){
        address_flag = read_more.getAttribute("data-address");
        if(address_flag == 0){
            address_content.style.maxHeight= "0px";
            read_more.setAttribute("data-address", "1");
        }
        else if(address_flag == 1){
            address_content.style.maxHeight= '25px'; 
            read_more.setAttribute("data-address", "0");
        }
    }
```

What is more:

- 'none' for css `overflow` do not exist (instead of that you could use `overflow: hidden` or `display: none`).
- `address_content` is more proper element of DOM for setting of `maxHeight` value (because on that element you set `overflow: hidden`, so maxHeight css would have some goal)

Comment: The set attribute functionality is working now but still the read more/less is not working I mean the content is not expanding . also I have change ```overflow :visible``` . but still not working. and thank you for your help

Comment: If you want animation/transition effect of expanding you could add ``transition`` css values to your element: 
```javascript
<p  class="address"  style="max-height:50px; overflow:hidden; transition: max-height 1s">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, illum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas esse suscipit temporibus consectetur iure quasi magni tenetur quia reprehenderit nesciunt, a nobis, quidem autem consequatur, hic aperiam modi excepturi delectus quo odio quaerat. Skunt id illo praesentium dolorum, inventore iusto?
    </p>
```